# Tailwind purge with Nx, no ProjectGraph error

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, nrwl-nx

The documentation here: https://nx.dev/l/r/guides/using-tailwind-css-in-react#introducing-nx-utility-for-better-tailwind-purging suggests to use `createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname)` for ease of maintenance.

I am using this from '@nrwl/angular/tailwind', not '@nrwl/react/tailwind'.

When I use this and trigger a build of my app, I get the following errors:

`[createGlobPatternsForDependencies] WARNING: There was no ProjectGraph available to read from, returning an empty array of glob patterns`

**Q: How can I resolve this?**

I can run `nx dep-graph` and the dependency graph generates fine.

**EDIT**: I debugged this, and `__dirname` documentation says *workspace relative directory path that will be used to infer the parent project and dependencies*
but then it fails later on line 20 of `generate-globs.js` because `filenameRelativeToWorkspaceRoot` is the '', i.e. its trying to find a project name but `__dirname` is the workspace name itself?

so

`purge: createGlobPatternsForDependencies(join(__dirname, 'apps/simple-app')),`

doesn't give the ProjectGraph error but

`purge: createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),` does

Comment: So out of curiosity, does `purge: createGlobPatternsForDependencies(join(__dirname, 'apps/simple-app')),` actually purge correctly, when not in JIT mode?

Comment: It worked for me but only for the one app and only with setting `enabled: true` which meant it would also purge for local dev. There was a separate issue with NODE_ENV not coming through.

Comment: We also encountered this problem when we tried to add tailwind to a project with circular dependencies. The inner method of `createGlobPatternsForDependencies` was throwing `callstack exceeded` error and the 
`[createGlobPatternsForDependencies] WARNING: There was no ProjectGraph available to read from, returning an empty array of glob patterns`
was shown instead.

Comment: yes so that is the expected error for circular dependencies. whereas in this case there were no circular dependencies but it still failed to build the project graph because it wasn't coping with glob-ing for all apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also posted on Github which raised the issue of the Nx documentation being based around React.

Since I posed this question, a blog post has been written: https://blog.nrwl.io/set-up-tailwind-css-with-angular-in-an-nx-workspace-6f039a0f4479

and documentation is on the Nx web site: https://nx.dev/guides/using-tailwind-css-with-angular-projects

but the key learning for this is **have a separate Tailwind config file per app**.

you can have a preset with shared Tailwind config and consume that, but the `createGlobPatternsForDependencies` expects to be per app, so then the `__dirname` being the project name makes a whole lot more sense...

If at that point you still get `[createGlobPatternsForDependencies] WARNING: There was no ProjectGraph available to read from, returning an empty array of glob patterns` then there is possibly a circular dependency preventing the code from executing, its possible to debug the `tailwind.js` file in *node_modules/@nrwl/angular/* to see.

Comment: I have two apps and the following dependencies `[a] -> [lib-a]` and `[b] -> [lib-a]`. While the **first app works fine** and processes the Tailwind Classes of the library, the **second one doesn't**. **Both have the** the "[createGlobPatternsForDependencies] WARNING: There was no ProjectGraph available to read from, returning an empty array of glob patterns
" warnings. While I have no idea what it else could be, it's weird that the first IS working despite not returning the patterns for my library

Answer (score 2):

I am neither sure if that is the right solution or if it helps anyone but me. But resetting the nx workspace with `nx reset` did the job for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and my issue came from a misconfiguration from the project.json files of one library inside the workspace. Apparently the `sourceRoot` changed when one member of our team migrate to a newer version of NX and the `sourceRoot` all changed and my colleague forgot one library that broke everything.